# Port in docker container not accessible

Tags: docker, port, iptables, portforwarding, docker-container

I have published four ports from container to host, but only three (8080, 33099, 37017) of those are accessible. This is how docker container looks:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                    NAMES
cdbc07f875ea        test:latest   "bash"              35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33098-33099->33098-33099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:37017->37017/tcp   test1
```

iptables on docker host:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:37017
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:33099
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:33098
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:37017 to:172.17.0.2:37017
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33099 to:172.17.0.2:33099
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33098 to:172.17.0.2:33098
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.17.0.2:8080
```

Any idea, why 33098 port is not accessible?

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` command or your `docker-compose.yml` file, and if it’s relevant, the `Dockerfile` you used to build a custom image?  Where are you trying to connect from and how?

Comment: Here is command for creating container: `docker run -d --name=test1 --hostname=test1.local -it --mount src=test-config-vol,dst=/config/ --mount src=test-storage-vol,dst=/storage/ -p 8080:8080 -p 33098-33099:33098-33099 -p 37017:37017  test:latest bash`. This docker engine is running in virtual server (ubuntu) in virtual box. So I'm trying to connect from host computer, where virtualbox is installed.

Comment: how do you know port 33098 is not accessible ? could it be your application not listening to it ?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have a similar problem with redis

Comment: No, unfortunalety I didn't find a solution.